# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key'

Tags: python, json, twitter

I've been working on some code to parse Twitter data recently (not a programmer) and now I've come across another error I cannot figure out.

My goal is to call this function from the command line as such:  `cat file.json | python main.py > output.csv' .  I've not done much with functions yet, but hopefully I just have a simple error.

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/titan/Titan_share/Titan/twitterAPI/printTweets_v7.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/titan/Titan_share/Titan/twitterAPI/printTweets_v7.py", line 21, in main
    if tweet.has_key('retweeted_status'):
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'has_key'
```

**Code**

```
import json
import sys
import time

def main():

    for line in sys.stdin:
        line = line.strip()

        data = ''
        try:
            data = json.loads(line)
        except ValueError as detail:
            continue

        for tweet in data:

            tweet_time = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.strptime(data['created_at'],'%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y'))

            ## if the key 'retweeted_status' is in the dict, print 
            if tweet.has_key('retweeted_status'):
                print tweet_time , "\t" , tweet['id_str'], "\t" , tweet['user']['screen_name'] , "\t" , tweet['retweeted_status']['user']['screen_name'] , "\t" , "RETWEET" , "\t" , tweet['text']

            ## if there is a mention in the dict, print
            elif 'entities' in tweet and len(tweet['entities']['user_mentions']) > 0:
                for u2 in tweet['entities']['user_mentions']:
                    print tweet_time , "\t" , tweet['id_str'], "\t" , tweet['user']['screen_name'] , "\t" , u2['screen_name'] , "\t" , "MENTION" , "\t" , tweet['text']

            ## if there is no retweet and no mention, print
            else:
                print tweet_time , "\t" , tweet['id_str'], "\t" , tweet['user']['screen_name'] , "\t" , "\t" , "TWEET" , "\t" , tweet['text']

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `tweet` is a Unicode string (corresponds to JSON string) but you are trying to treat it like a dictionary (corresponds to JSON object). My guess, you should use `tweet = data` instead. Unrelated: use `'key' in some_dict` instead of `some_dict.has_key('key')`